# How to set this from Entity Framework using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-4

A while back, I fell into the fat controller trap when I was first working with MVC. My first app used EF4 to make all the models I needed. I just put all my logic into my controller actions. While it worked, it's definitely not the best practice way. To do it the right way I started trying to build my models based on my EF objects in an effort to follow the skinny controller concept.

I've run into a roadblock in trying to find the best way to populate my models. Is there a way to run a LINQ query and have it populate your model without having to iterate through the properties to set to another class?

Something like this:

```
// from EF model built from database
public class MyEFObject
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
}

public class MyObjectModel : MyEFObject
{
    private Entities _data = new Entities();
    public MyObjectModel(int? id)
    {
        if(id.HasValue) // get an existing record
        {
           this = _data.MyEFObjects.Where(m => m.ID.Equals(id)).Single();
           // or populate right out of the query
           _data.MyEFObjects.Where(m => m.ID.Equals(id))
                         .Select(o => new {
                            this.ID = o.ID,
                            this.Name = o.Name,
                            this.Title = o.Title
                          }); 
        }
        else
        {
           // set defaults for a new MyObjectModel
        }  
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        // takes the current object and saves changes
    }
}
```

I know you can add a function to the EF Entity object, but I like having the option to Create or Update all tied up in one call (Save method). I don't see the point messing with a model if I have to essentially recreate what I already have from my EF Object. If I simply have a method on a class that accepts a populated object, the concept of a usable model for my views is negated.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is have a domain model, ef model and and **adapter**. I think this keeps the code pretty clean and nicely separates the mapping logic.

```
//Domain model to decouple from EF
public class MyObjectModel
{ 
    public int ID {get; set;} 
    public string Name {get; set;} 
    public string Title {get; set;} 
} 

//Auto generated Entity Framework class
public class MyEFObject
{ 
    public int ID {get; set;} 
    public string Name {get; set;} 
    public string Title {get; set;} 
} 

//Adapter responsible for mapping your data to your domain model
public class MyObjectModelAdapter : MyEFObject
{
    public MyObjectModelAdapter(MyEFObject entity)
    {
        if(entity != null)
        {
            this.ID = entity.ID;
            this.Name = entity.Name;
            this.Title = entity.Title;
        }
        else 
        { 
           // set defaults for a new MyObjectModel 
        }  
    }
}
```

Then the basic usage would be:

```
new Entities().MyEFObjects.ToList().Select(x => new MyObjectModelAdapter(x));
```

OR

```
new MyObjectModelAdapter(new Entities().MyEFObjects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID.Equals(objectId)));
```

If you specifically require a list of MyObjectModel then you could do the following:

```
new Entities().MyEFObjects.ToList().Select(x => new MyObjectModelAdapter(x) as MyObjectModel);
```

OR

```
new MyObjectModelAdapter(new Entities().MyEFObjects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID.Equals(objectId)) as MyObjectModel;
```

Of course you don't want to chain your entity context together like that, it is just to show usage.

Comment: It won't work with EF because projecting into a type with a parameter in its constructor is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

Comment: @Slauma Thanks for pointing that out, there was a mistake in my solution. ToList should be called before hand in order to execute the query first. I've used this method for some time and it works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Slauma is right. LINQ to Entities won't accept it. I tried a couple of versions of what was posted and I only found my self with a kludgy mess. I got it to the point where I could set instance values, but by then EF wouldn't register a change had been made and defeating the whole purpose. There may be a way to do this, but as of now, the steps to make it work seem to be overkill.

I ended up with something like this:

```
public class MyObjectModel : MyEFObject
{
    public void Save(int? id, MyObjectModel model)
    {
       var data = new Entities();
       MyEFObject foo;
       if(id.HasValue)
       {  
           foo = data.MyEFObjects.Where(e => e.ID.Equals(id.Value)).Single();
       }
       else
       {
           foo = new MyEFObject();
       }
       foo.Name = model.Name; 
       foo.Title = model.Title;

       if(!id.HasValue)
       {
          data.MyEFObjects.AddObject(foo);
       }

       data.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I didn't want to have to work with two instances of my model, but it works and I have my lean controller action.

Comment: My mistake, I mistyped something in my solution. I've updated the post and added a comment.